# ELB & Spring Boot: Getting error "(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream" even though server port is properly configured?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm very new to AWS in general, and I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application through Elastic Beanstalk.

However, the logs show the following errors:

```
2017/12/24 05:16:53 [error] 3114#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.18.82, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.15.157"
2017/12/24 05:16:53 [error] 3114#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.7.216, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "172.31.15.157"
```

And these errors continue for a little bit...

I've searched around for this issue (on Stack Overflow and other forums), and they all suggest that the server port needs to be changed to 5000.

I've done that by setting the environment variable `SERVER_PORT` to 5000, and it looks like the spring boot app is starting properly in the correct port because the following is displayed in the logs:

```
2017-12-24 19:40:16.239  INFO 20086 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http)
```

So the port is not the issue.

I did build the environment in a VPC, and so I figured it might be a security group causing this issue. So I (temporarily) allowed all traffic for incoming rules and outgoing rules for the VPC Security Group and the Load Balancer Security Group. This didn't make a difference either.

Right now, I'm pretty much stumped and don't know what else to try.

Comment: So I actually just switched the environment type from "Load balancing, auto scaling" to "Single instance", and it works now. So I'm assuming there's some configuration with the load balancer that I need to make, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was just a dumb error on my part. The URL I had configured to the Elastic Beanstalk for the health check was protected by Spring Security.

So I just opened up an endpoint which is not protected, and everything works fine.